# MySql in DNX 5.0

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I would like to ask- **is it possible to connect to MySql database in DNX Core 5.0?** In my project I need to do web api and I have vNext Class Library project that should connect to MySql database and manipulate the data in this database. But...

I have the newest .net/connector installed. I have downloaded the MySql.Data NuGet package and in references it is added to both- DNX 4.5.1 and Core 5.0 as well. But I get error- **functions such as open the connection to my database, execute query etc are not available in DNX Core 5.0.** The code is working in Visual Studio 2013 and in DNX 4.5.1 as well. I am not able to find any answer how to connect in DNX Core 5.0 to MySql (neither if it is even possible).

*I was advised to downolad the source code of the newest connector/net* and copy the code for MySql.Data to new vNext Class Library project and add reference to my Class Library that is supposed to access the database. But I have approx 1600 errors. *I was told to solve them one by one.* But that seems to be even bigger problem. It looks like it would be possible to solve by adding several references but I cannot find the equivalent reference that would work for DNX Core 5.0. **Is this a good approach?**

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You're aware of that you can just remove Core 5.0 from the "frameworks" section in project.json so that you don't need your other dependencies to be Core 5 compliant?

Running towards dnx 4.5.1 (which includes all .net versions from and above 4.5.1 , ie. 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6 etc.) should be what most people want unless you need a fully platform independent deployment, which is what Core is meant for.

Comment: And you probably don't need EF 7 either, EF 6 with MySQL should work fine, or don't use EF at all (which is what I do). A MicroORM or NHibernate are good alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Saldy it's not in EntityFramework 7 yet, my understanding is that they're not prioritizing it for the initial release that's scheduled in January.

Read more:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Using-EF7-in-Traditional-.NET-Applications

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question running.

[DNXCORE 5.0 and mysql / mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577533/dnxcore-5-0-and-mysql-mariadb)

At this moment it is not possible to run MySQL and DNX 5.0! If you want to use it with DNX, you have to fall back on 4.5.1 ( and use mono for Linux environments )

This is because there is no connector available for MySQL. 
If applicable, you can use postgresql with DNX 5.0 in stead of MySQL/MariaDB