# How to use EF6 and MySql with the dnxcore50 framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, dnx

I am trying to use EF6 with a MySql Database using dnxcore50. The code for the database repository has already been made and I am trying to move it to the new framework but I have a lot of missing references for the following:

```
EntityTypeConfiguration
DbContext
MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration
DbConfigurationType
DbSet
and more
```

Here is my project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "System.Data.Entity.Repository": "2.0.0.1",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23109",
    "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.0.10-beta-23109",
    "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.10-beta-23109",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-23109",
    "WNCT.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "MySql.Data.Entity.EF6": "6.8.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-*",
    "MySql.Data.Entities": "6.8.3",
    "StructureMap": "3.1.6.186",
    "MySql.Web": "6.9.7",
    "MySql.Data": "6.9.7"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": { }
    }
  }
```

I can't phantom what am I missing. Does anyone know how to set this up?

Comment: As of August 2015, the MySql.Data package doesn't provide a build for DNXCore framework. (EF6 too, use EF7 in ASP.NET 5 projects)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278301

Comment: @amartynov does EF7 work with MySQL? Last I checked it didn't